# TSQL - Join two groups of category together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I'd like to regroup my date into groups based on two columns. The data below shows what my data look like. I can't post you a nice picture because I'm new here but the resume should be clear enough.

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| X1  | X2  | Result |
+-----+-----+--------+
|   4 |   1 | A      |
|   4 |   2 | A      |
|   1 |   3 | B      |
|   2 |   3 | B      |
|   3 |   4 | C      |
|   3 |   5 | C      |
|   1 |   6 | B      |
|   2 |   6 | B      |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

I have two columns indicating categories my data belong to. I'd like to regroup them into group where they all belong together in one group category or another. I'd like to find an efficient query for this.

At the moment, I've thought about making a join to have which element are linked to which with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] T1
JOIN [Table] T2 ON T1.Gr1 = T2.Gr1 OR T1.Gr2 = T2.Gr2
```

With that I could build a recursive query that starts with the first element and add another to the next group if it's linked somehow to it or add it to a new rank if it doesn't. With a lot of data, it doesn't seem very elegant nor efficient.

Anyone has a solution?

EDIT. I realize my question isn't clear. Each row has two categorical variables X1 and X2. I want to split all the observations in group that share nothing in common. In the exemple, the group B hold all the observations that have X1 = 1 or 2 or X2 = 3 or 6. The group C hold the observations with x1 = 3 and x2 = 4 or 5. I hope this make things more clear.

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward but I don't understand what you want for output. And it is good you didn't post a picture of your data, you should always post data as text.

Comment: The last column show the result I want. In short, I want to regroup my data such that they are in a closed group. No observations in group A share a category with the observations in group B or C.

Comment: I am sure this makes sense to you. But from where I sit the output is just random. You want A, B, C. What are the rules? There is no clarity about why the first two rows are a group. And why the two sets of 1, 2 are a group. You need to explain the rules here because we don't know what this data represents of what you are trying to do with it. Put in some effort in the explanation and answer will find you usually pretty quickly.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand your output. Result A has 1 and 2 as Gr2. Result B has 1 and 2 as Gr1 as well as 3 and 6 as Gr2. What is the logic that defines a result?

Comment: Thank you for the update, however doesn't result A still have X1 in common and result B has X2 in common for 2 separate sets (3 & 6)? Why are some broken by X1 and some broken by X2?

Comment: It would really help if your `data` was in fact just `data` and not a `result`.  (i.e. provide data and also provide the wanted result as 2 different things) Also the query uses column names GR1 and GR2 that do not appear in your data X1 and X2, so while this may make sense to you, it is just confusing to me.

Comment: can't you post output expected ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to achieve.

*To clarify, I think you want to create **new groups** on the fly as some sort of pointer goes through a list of X1/X2 pairs.  If either X1 **OR** X2 have already been seen, add it to the existing group, otherwise add it to a new group.*

This fairly unconventional for database-side calculations as it doesn't fall into the usual set-based theory around which RDBMS's are designed.  For example: which group does an item go into if it matches two previous rows which are in different groups?

This can be done with a cursor, but I hate cursors, so I'm not going to go there (at least not yet).  I think there is a way to achieve this with [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/).

Here's a fairly rough example of how you might achieve it - bear in mind, the nuances of this logic may not quite fit what you're expecting, as per my duplicate rows note above.  This one assumes that the input data has some sort of ordered/unique key to it, proceeds through the rows and creates new groups as required, and if duplicate matches are found it only matches the first instance.

*This may very well be extremely slow on large tables* (...so user beware and all that stuff):

```
declare @t table (
     i int identity, -- here's our ordered key
     X1 int,
     X2 int
);

-- Here's our test data (a few extra rows added on for good measure
insert into @t 
values (4, 1),(4, 2),(1, 3),(2, 3),(3, 4),(3, 5),(1, 6),
       (2, 6),(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 5),(7, 7),(4, 1),(1, 2),
       (9, 9),(9, 1)

; with cte as ( 
-- keep track of the newest group number (by summing the "new group" flags):
select i, X1, X2, sum(newgrp) over (order by i) newestGroupNo 
    from (
        -- This subquery flags whenever there is a row that doesn't 
        -- match any previous row, and a new group should be created
        select X1, X2, i, 
            case when 
                (count(*) over (partition by X1 order by i)) = 1 and -- unique over X1
                (count(*) over (partition by X2 order by i)) = 1 -- unique over X2
            then 1 -- New group
            else 0 -- Existing group
            end newgrp
        from @t
    ) b
)
-- Now do the uniqueness check again, but either return the new group no, 
-- or the group no of the first group that matches prior to this row
select i, X1, X2, 
        case when 
            (count(*) over (partition by X1 order by i)) = 1 and -- unique over X1
            (count(*) over (partition by X2 order by i)) = 1 -- unique over X2
        then newestGroupNo -- New group, return the group number
        else (select top 1 newestGroupNo 
              from cte 
              where (cte.X1 = c.X1 or cte.X2 = c.X2) and cte.i <= c.i) -- Existing group
        end grp
from cte c order by i
```

Results:

```
i   X1  X2  grp
1   4   1   1     new group
2   4   2   1     match on X1 where i=1
3   1   3   2     no match
4   2   3   2     match on X2 where i=3
5   3   4   3     no match
6   3   5   3     match on X1 where i=5
7   1   6   2     match on X1 where i=3
8   2   6   2     match on X1 where i=4 (not i=7)
9   2   1   1     match on X2 where i=1 (not i=4 or i=8)
10  2   2   1     match on X2 where i=2 (... etc)
11  2   5   2     match on X1 where i=4
12  7   7   4     no match
13  4   1   1     match on X1 where i=1
14  1   2   1     match on X2 where i=2
15  9   9   5     no match
16  9   1   1     match on X2 where i=1
```

Does this do what you expect?  If you have large tables to process, be sure to test this, there are almost certainly faster ways to achieve this in a stored procedure, but this gives you a single query which could be put into a view if required.

Improvements to the script above welcomed.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not sure it would work well on my database though, I have about 500 000 observations and the category are represented by text and unique identifier. I'll look into this. Thanks